# as3xls special characters error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I can create the excel file just fine, the only problem is that when a field has a special character it shows up like so: Â®

Is there something I should be doing before I save the file out?

Comment: There is something presumably wrong with the encoding in as3xls. It is opensource code, you can modify it and share your fixes.

Comment: can you show your input/special character...?
@Pranav Hosangadi  as he said that it is open source, so you can edit/debug the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/)

Comment: The special character is the registered symbol ® .  The end result in the spreadsheet is Â®.  I'll take a look at the source and see if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version of the **as3xls** library that can handle special characters and solves other issues

[GitHub version as3xls](https://github.com/djw/as3xls)

Download a ZIP of the library and include the "src/com" source files into your Flash Builder project